# Hide vertical scroll bar in ListBox control

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I'm developing an application that requires a `ListBox` control. Unfortunately, when I add too many items in the `ListBox`, a vertical scroll bar is shown. Is there something I can do to hide the vertical scroll bar shown by the `ListBox`? I can see that there's a property to hide the horizontal scroll bar but there's no property for the vertical scroll bar.

Comment: If you remove the vertical scroll bar then how would users access the items past the edge of the scroll?

Comment: @LeeTaylor Thanks for replying. I've forgot to mention that I have a RichTextBox. I've managed to control the listbox within the RichTextBox. So, there's no need to show scroll bars in the listbox. Have a great day :)

Comment: OK, I'm not aware of any way to remove the scroll bars. The only way I know is to make sure the listbox is long enough to hold all your items.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was solved. I've simply created a new project of template a class library with the following code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class MyListBox : System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
    {
        private bool mShowScroll;
        protected override System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
                if (!mShowScroll)
                    cp.Style = cp.Style & ~0x200000;
                return cp;
            }
        }
        public bool ShowScrollbar
        {
            get { return mShowScroll; }
            set
            {
                if (value != mShowScroll)
                {
                    mShowScroll = value;
                    if (IsHandleCreated)
                        RecreateHandle();
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Then, I've built the project outputting a new class library **`ClassLibrary1.dll`**

On my main project, I've right-clicked the **`ToolBox`** and selected **`Choose Items...`**. Clicked on **Browse...** and selected the class library that I've recently created (ClassLibrary1.dll) and clicked on **Open** then on **OK**. Thus, I was able to have my custom `ListBox` which has no vertical scroll bars anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Except from the horizontal scroll-bar, there is no way with normal use you can turn off the vertical scroll-bar.

You can only set it always visible or auto using the property `ScrollAlwaysVisible` (also in VB).

When you add item you can instead re-calculate ClientSize by calculating, something like this (untested, you might need to add Padding values to it as well):

```
 Size sz = new Size(ListBox1.ClientSize.Width, _
                    ListBox1.Items.Count * ListBox1.Font.Height);
 ListBox1.ClientSize = sz
```

Of course, you should add check to the value in case it is zero, and/or you want a minimum/maximum height.

Comment: Thank you, I've successfully hid the vertical scroll bar creating a class library. I'll post my solution in a moment :)

Comment: Nice :-) As you asked if it could be done with the ListBox control I'll leave my answer as-is :-)